# Как сделать расстояния между ячейками таблицы, чтобы при этом по краям этой таблицы отступов от ячеек не было?

Tags: html, css, таблицы

Если задавать таблице `border-spacing: 5px;`, например, то отступы появляются не только внутри вокруг ячеек, но и по краям также появляются отступы. Как желательно без костылей сделать, чтобы по краям (отмечены красными стрелками) не было отступов?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вот-так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант — отрицательные поля, равные значению `border-spacing`.

```css
table { 
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    margin: -10px;
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Ваше решение самое простое, правильное, понятное и без костылей.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/bc3zutny/19/

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>border-spacing</title>
  <style>
   table {
    border: 4px double #333; /* Рамка вокруг таблицы */ 
    border-collapse: separate; /* Способ отображения границы */ 
    width: 100%; /* Ширина таблицы */ 
    /*border-spacing: 50px 45px;  Расстояние между ячейками */ 
   }
   td {
    padding: 5px; /* Поля вокруг текста */ 
    border: 1px solid #a52a2a; /* Граница вокруг ячеек */ 

   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>111111111</td>
    <td style="border: 0px"></td>
    <td>3333333</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="border: 0px;"></td>
    <td style="border: 0px;"></td>
    <td style="border: 0px;"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>111111111</td>
    <td style="border: 0px;"></td>
    <td>3333333</td>
   </tr>

  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я добавил скрин к своему вопросу

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду отступы по горизонтали и вертикали, то в [border-spacing: 5px 45px] первый отступ слева и справа от ячеек, второй - снизу и сверху.

Comment: Посмотрите как нужно, прикрепил скрин к вопросу...

Comment: Я внимательно перечитал ваш вопрос. На вашем месте я бы не использовал border-spacing, а прикостылил бы пустые ячейки и задал бы им свойства "border: 0px;" https://jsfiddle.net/bc3zutny/18/

Answer (score 0):

Это не таблица, но как вариант можно использовать.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
}

.grid__cell {
  border: 1px solid lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__cell">1111111111111111</div>
  <div class="grid__cell">2222222222222222</div>
  <div class="grid__cell">3333333333333333</div>
  <div class="grid__cell">4444444444444444</div>
</div>
```